# How to fix incompatible Parquet schema error in Impala

Tags: pyspark, hive, parquet, impala

Experts, i am querying a Hive external table (Data stored as Parquet on HDFS) without any issue using Hive/Pyspark. The same query when run on Impala is giving me "Incompatible Parquet Schema" error. The field is defined as 'String' in Hive DDL and only value it has is '000'.

Error-

```
File 'hdfs://home/user1/out/STATEMENTS/effective_dt=20200804/part-00007-79ea7da3-2165-4a92-9c30-a11e415e778c.c000' has an incompatible Parquet schema for column 'db.statements.profit'. Column type: CHAR(3), Parquet schema: optional int32 os_chargeoff [i:144 d:1 r:0]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I tried different things - Refresh Table/Invalidate Metadata/Drop recreate Table without success.